# Wp_query partial random

Tags: php, wordpress

Let's say I have 100+ paginated posts in wordpress.

Is it possible for single wp_query to resulting in:

- 10 posts will be picked randomly and placed first.
- The rest (90+) are sorted by default and placed after the first 10 random posts.

thank you.

Comment: It's not possible for a query to output it like this. I'd try to use `get_posts` to get all posts you need in a table and then display the random 10 while removing them from the array (or just change their position).

Answer (score 0):

Don't mind my comment before. Here's how to rearrange single wp query

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'numberposts'   =>  -1,
    'post_type'     =>  'post',
));

$a = $the_query->posts;

$ta = array_rand($a, 10);
for($i=0;$i<count($ta);$i++) {
    $res = array_splice($a, $ta[$i], 1);
    $ta[$i] = $res[0];
}
$a = array_merge($ta, $a);
$the_query->posts = $a;
```